# Max size production kafka cluster deployment for now

Tags: apache-kafka

I am considering how to deploy our kafka cluster: a big cluster with several broker groups or several clusters. If a big cluster, I want to know how big a kafka cluster can be. kafka has a controller node and I don't know how many brokers it can support. And another one is _consume_offset_ topic ,how big it can be and can we add more partitions to it.

Answer (score 1):

I've personally worked with production Kafka clusters anywhere from 3 brokers to 20 brokers. They've all worked fine, it just depends on what kind of workload you're throwing at it.  With Kafka, my general recommendation is that it's better to have a smaller amount of larger/more-powerful brokers, than having a bunch of tiny servers.

For a standing cluster, each broker you add increases "crosstalk" between the nodes, since they have to move partitions around, replicate data, as well as maintain the metadata in sync. This additional network chatter can impact how much load the broker can handle.  As a general rule, adding brokers will add overall capacity, but you have to shift partitions around so that the load will be balanced properly across the entire cluster.  Because of that, it's much better to start with 10 nodes, so that topics and partitions will be spread out evenly from the beginning, than starting out with 6 nodes and then adding 4 nodes later.

Regardless of the size of the cluster, there is always only one controller node at a time. If that node happens to go down, another node will take over as controller, but only one can be active at a given time, assuming the cluster is not in an unstable state.

The `__consumer_offsets` topic can have as many partitions as you want, but it comes by default set to 50 partitions.  Since this is a compacted topic, assuming that there is no excessive committing happening (this has happened to me twice already in production environments), then the default settings should be enough for almost any scenario. You can look up the configuration settings for consumer offsets topics by looking for broker properties that start with `offsets.` in the official Kafka documentation.

You can get more details at the official Kafka docs page: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/

Comment: thank you. I may have a 200+ node cluster, I think it will be very different. As you have met excessive committing problem on __consumer_offset__ topic, i think this may be a problem for big size cluster.

Answer (score 0):

The size of a cluster can be determined by the following ways.

The most accurate way to model your use case is to simulate the load you expect on your own hardware.You can use the [kafka load generation tools](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Performance+testing) `kafka-producer-perf-test` and `kafka-consumer-perf-test`.

Based on the producer and consumer metrics, we can decide the number of brokers for our cluster.

The other approach is without simulation, which is based on the estimated rate at which you get data that required data retention period.

We can also calculate the throughput and based on that we can also decide the number of brokers in our cluster.

**Example**

If you have 800 messages per second, of 500 bytes each then your throughput is `800*500/(1024*1024) = ~0.4MB/s`. Now if your topic is partitioned and you have 3 brokers up and running with 3 replicas that would lead to `0.4/3*3=0.4MB/s`.

More details about the architecture are available at [confluent](https://www.confluent.io/wp-content/uploads/apache-kafka-confluent-enterprise-ref-architecture.pdf).

Within a Kafka Cluster, a single broker works as a **controller**. If you have a cluster of 100 brokers then one of them will act as the controller.

If we talk internally, each broker tries to create a node(ephemeral node) in the zookeeper(/controller). The first one becomes the controller. The other brokers get an exception("node already exists"), they set a watch on the controller. When the controller dies, the ephemeral node is removed and watching brokers are notified for the controller selection process.

The functionality of the controller can be found [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Kafka+Controller+Internals).

The `__consumer_offset` topic is used to store the offsets committed by consumers. Its default value is 50 but it can be set for more partitions. To change, set the `offsets.topic.num.partitions` property.